# Attaching Old (Local) Commits as Parent Commits to Initial Commit By Another Local Repo Forcefully Pushing Commit Accidentally

Tags: git, github

I had an old local repo with many commits `A -- B -- C -- D` pushed to the remote master branch.
I created another new local repo and tried to push its commits `AA -- BB -- CC` to the same remote branch.

The intention was to push the new repo without `git pull` and rebasing, essentially not wanting to relate previous remote commit history and just needing to push new local repo to remote branch e.g `D --> AA` where AA has no related history with D

```
Old repo: A -- B -- C -- D
                          \
New repo:                  AA -- BB -- CC
```

But I accidentally ran `git push --force`, and the entire previous remote history reset (see below)

```
 deleted (A -- B -- C -- D)
                            AA -- BB -- CC
```

Now I want to somehow use my old repo with local commits history and attach all previous local commits `A -- B -- C -- D` of it as the parent commits to the initial commit `AA` of new repo in same remote branch

How should I go about achieving this?

---

**Regarding Answer Below**

To make things clearer. Please see the details of my two repos below:

- Old repo:

```
- Name: origin
- Checkout url: https://ABC.git
- Commits: A, B , C, D
- Local path: E:\proj_v1
- Branch: 1 (master)
```

- New Repo:

```
- Name: origin
- Checkout url: Same as above (pointing to same remote repo)
- Commits: AA, BB, CC
- Local path: E:\proj_v2
- Branch: 1 (master)
```

Comment: Have you tried rebasing D on AA and then deleting all D files?

Comment: Unsure how to do it. Can you add it as an answer, plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, an important thing to understand: the parent(s) of a commit are part of its immutable identity, and cannot be changed. What you can do is create new commits which are the same *other than* their parent(s).

Secondly, it is actually possible to have two branches in a repository which have no history in common at all. You just need to have branch names pointing at both so that they don't get "garbage collected".

In fact, you need to start with this before you can do anything else. If you have the two repositories checked out locally, you can add one as a "remote" of the other, and fetch the commits.

In the new repo (E:\proj_v2) run this:

```sh
# To make things clearer, I'll use a branch called "new_master" to point at the commits from the new repo
git branch new_master master
# Now fetch the commits from the other repo, and call them "original_master":
git remote add old_repo E:\proj_v1
git fetch old_repo
git branch original_master old_repo/master
```

You will now have something like this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D <- original_master

AA -- BB -- CC <- new_master
```

You could then merge the two together using [the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---allow-unrelated-histories):

```sh
git switch new_master
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories original_master
```

Creating a history with two "roots":

```
A -- B -- C -- D  <- original_master
                \
                 X <- new_master
                /
 AA -- BB -- CC
```

However, the desired situation you describe is that the new commits appear to have happened on top of the original history. The way to do that is using the `git rebase` command, which takes a series of commits, and *recreates them* on top of a new parent.

```sh
git switch new_master
git rebase --root --onto original_master
```

This will create a new history that looks like this (note that the commits "AA", "BB", and "CC" will be recreated with new commit hashes):

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- AA2 -- BB2 -- CC2
               ^                   ^
               |                   |
           original_master     new_master
```

Note that while recreating commit "AA", git will try to apply it as a patch on top of commit "D", which will probably lead to conflicts. You will need to resolve it by removing all the code inherited from "D", and keeping only the parts from "AA". I think you should be able to that with `git restore --source=AA .`

Comment: Apologies but I didn't quite understand. I've added new section in my question above for further clarity. I'd appreciate if you could talk about the steps/ commands in light of the details given above :)

Comment: @Waleed93 I have replaced "main" with "master", and "/path/to/old/checkout" with "E:\proj_v1"; does that help? I'm not sure what other details to add.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. But on running 2nd command (fetching commits from old repo), I'm getting error: `fatal: E:\proj_v1: 'E:\proj_v1' is outside repository`

Comment: @Waleed93 Oh, I made a typo, sorry: it should be `git remote add` not `git add remote` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote not https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've been very helpful